# dataset doesn't update anything in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, sqlcommandbuilder

I have written this procedure in ms-sql

```sql
ALTER proc [dbo].[gravacliente]
AS
SELECT
    idcliente, Nome, Endere, tel_empresa, celular,
    UF, CEP, Email, Contato, Referencia, OBS, Nasc,
    cpf, cnpj, Iest
FROM
    tbcliente
```

and this code, too

```
DataSet grava = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommandBuilder constru6 = new SqlCommandBuilder(da2);
SqlCommand llena8 = new SqlCommand("gravacliente", conec1);
llena8.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
da2.SelectCommand = llena8;
da2.Fill(grava, "tbcliente");
DataRow dr = grava.Tables["tbcliente"].NewRow();
dr.BeginEdit();
dr["nome"] = txtNome.Text;
dr["endere"] = txendere.Text; 
dr.EndEdit();
da2.Update(grava.Tables["tbcliente"]);
label9.Text = txtNome.Text;
```

`conec1` is working but the above code doesn't update anything. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must add the row to the table.

```
DataRow dr = grava.Tables["tbcliente"].NewRow();

dr["nome"] = txtNome.Text;
dr["endere"] = txendere.Text; 

grava.Tables["tbcliente"].AddRow(dr);
```

Also, AFAIK, the `SqlCommandBuilder` won't work with a stored proc. You must either provide an update command to your adapter or use a text-based select command:

```
SqlCommand llena8 = new SqlCommand("SELECT idcliente, Nome, Endere, tel_empresa, celular, UF, CEP, Email, Contato, Referencia, OBS, Nasc, cpf, cnpj, Iest FROM tbcliente", conec1);
```

Of course, you will also need to call this before doing the update:

```
constru6.GetUpdateCommand();
```

My recommendation would be that you don't use `SqlCommandBuilder` at all because of the extra overhead it costs. If however you insist on using it I'd suggest that you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: True, but it still won't work; the DataAdapter doesn't know how to update the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a valid select in the argument for `SqlDataAdapter`

```
string sql = @"
SELECT
    idcliente, Nome, Endere, tel_empresa, celular,
    UF, CEP, Email, Contato, Referencia, OBS, Nasc,
    cpf, cnpj, Iest
FROM
    tbcliente
";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string");
DataSet grava = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
SqlCommandBuilder constru6 = new SqlCommandBuilder(da2);
```

This is based on the constructor for `SqlDataAdapter` that takes a string for selection, and a connection.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2d3kh8d(v=vs.110).aspx

This website has a great reference implementation on using `SqlDataAdapter` and `SqlCommandBuilder`

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommandbuilder

The canononical example for a class in msdn is very similar too.
[SqlCommandBuilder Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder#exampleToggle)